# Multiple "Journey Entry: Audience" steps in an automation?

Tags: marketing-cloud, journeybuilder, automationstudio

Is it possible for one automation to have multiple "Journey Entry: Audience" steps? I have an automation that will be running a few queries, and from there I want some contacts to enter Journey A, and some contacts to enter journey B. Is this possible to build within the same automation?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can only have one entry source in Journey Builder right now. For what you're describing, you would have to run two journeys. Unless there was some column for the decision splitter that had "if 'A' then..." and it would go through the "true" line of the Journey.

Answer (score 0):

I had the similar requirement and was achieved using the below code. If we have all the Journeys to be built as **API entry** source.

```
%%[
 /*Based on your required field segregate your contacts*/
SET @specific_field = QueryParameter('Logic_field')

  IF @specific_field == "A" THEN            
    SET @eventkey = "APIEvent-xxxxxx"       //send to Journey with API entry A

  ELSEIF @specific_field == "B" THEN
    SET @eventkey = "APIEvent-xxxxxx"       //send to Journey with API entry B

  ELSEIF @specific_field == "C" THEN
    SET @eventkey = "APIEvent-xxxxxx"       //send to Journey with API entry C

  ELSE
    SET @eventkey = "APIEvent-xxxxxxx"      //send to Journey with API entry Default
  ENDIF
 /*Generating the AccessToken using client id and secret key*/
    VAR @callstatus, @response
    SET @payload = '{"client_id": "xxxxxxxx", "client_secret": "xxxxxxx", "grant_type": "client_credentials"}'
    SET @accessToken = HTTPPost2("https://xxxxxxxxxxxxxx.auth.marketingcloudapis.com/v2/token", "application/json", @payload, True, @callstatus, @response)
]%% 
<script runat="server">
  /*Getting variables from AMPscript to SSJS*/
  Platform.Load("core", "1"); 
  var specific_field = Variable.GetValue("@specific_field");
  var eventkey_ = Variable.GetValue("@eventkey")
  var accessTok = Variable.GetValue("@callstatus");
  var response_ = Platform.Function.ParseJSON(accessTok);
  var accessToken_ = response_.access_token;
  var content_ = {"ContactKey": leadid_, "EventDefinitionKey":eventkey_, "EstablishContactKey": true, "Data": { "specific_field":specific_field}}
  var strContent_ = Platform.Function.Stringify(content_)
  Variable.SetValue("@token_",'Bearer '+accessToken_); 
  Variable.SetValue("@content",strContent_);
</script>
%%[
/*Calling Journey entry Event REST API*/
ENDIF
var @statusCode
var @response
SET @post = HTTPPost2("https://xxxxxxxxx.rest.marketingcloudapis.com/interaction/v1/events","application/json",@content,false,@statusCode, @response, "Authorization", @token_)
]%%

STATUS = %%=v(@statusCode)=%% <br/>
```