# whenever any data extension created in SFMC I would like to add this in Journey Builder as a entry source

Tags: marketing-cloud, journeybuilder, dataextensions

Per my business need I have below requirement-

From an third party app user can create data extension in SFMC by any name. In SFMC I have 3-4 pre built journey created on my account.

So whenever any data extension created in SFMC I would like to add this in my pre built Journeys. How this would be possible?

Example: Suppose I have 3 Journey created for Saving Account, Loan Account and Current Account. Now in our 3rd party app, user can create Data Extension and through API it will come in SFMC. Whenever Data Extension created in SFMC we would like to use this as a entry source in relevant Journey and send email.
If user have put name of DE as "Xyz" then in SMFC it will show "Xyz_Saving Account". By this we will be able to identify that it is related to which account and which Journey need to send.

Please let me know the way to do this.

Regards,
Alok

Comment: I am NOT clear on the requirement! .And as per my understanding you must use API entry rather than a DE entry ... hope this might help you..https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/218612/multiple-journey-entry-audience-steps-in-an-automation/283980#283980

Comment: Hi @VishalKumarCV in my use case there could be N number of DEs and we need to run Journey Builder separately for each one of them.

Comment: As per my knowledge, to build journeys with Data Extension as entry source, the DE should be ALREADY created, and cannot be connected after point of time! ....... hence my suggestion is to use API as entry source as your audience are coming from Third party app... JB BEST ENTRY SOURCE - BEST Practices .... `https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_jb_entry_sources.htm&type=0` ...and `https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_bp_entry_source_best_practices.htm&type=5`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

go for simple solution, instead of thinking about using a DE straight into your journeys i would recommend putting an identifier in your DE like column X = "savings account" if it's already there then you are good.

then use query builder/ Filter activity to find the relevant rows and inject into another DE which is associated with your contact model or used in the journey.

Let me know if that helps :)

Comment: I got your point. However there is not only a single DE that we are using. There could be multiple DEs, which is completely up to user what the name they put for DE. So, in this case Filter Activity/Query Builder would not be right approach.

Comment: Sorry if I'm not getting it right but why to create new DE for same type of data? i believe this issue needs a better consulting approach rather than technical assistance. To your original question there is no way you can use randomly created DEs within your journey.

Comment: Thanks Pragyanshu. This requirement is from client end.